# XCode 5 and XCode 5.1 side by side

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1

I have some apps on app store that support iOS 5 and above. XCode 5.1 doesn't support iOS 5 any more.

Can i have both, xcode 5 and xcode 5.1 side by side?

I m aware the fact that the update from xcode 5 to 5.1 is **not** a .dmg and just a simple update file.

Any help will great!
10X!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can download Xcode as .dmg file from Apple server.

You need to go to this link:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Make sure you logged in. In the list, you can find Xcode and download it as .dmg file

Comment: First link is broken :/

Answer (score 2):

make duplicate in of Xcode in Application folder with other name, I have 4 and 5 for older projects

Comment: @gran33 what you mean?